# How to reduce in-call volume (lower than 0) in android?

Tags: android, audio

My problem is the lowest volume in in-call mode still loud.
So I try this code

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio.setStreamVolume(audio.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, -1, 0);
```

But not effect, In-call volume is set to 0 and still loud.
Have any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to make the volume of the caller lower?  If so I suspect a minimum level is enforce by the mfg of the hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u r trying to silent the phone then try this out:

AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

and to enable volume:

audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't want to silent my phone. My problem is the lowest volume still loud. I need to reduce sound lower than standard. Now I use bluetooth and it can reduce sound like I need.